# Where is the current build variant value for each module stored in android studio?

Tags: android-studio

In a project of mine I have a bunch of modules as well as a lot of build variant. When ever I switch between branches specifically going from one branch to a branch with many new modules, I have to manually switch the build variant to the correct one for each new module which takes time especially since the project rebuilds each time the build variant is changed. I have the plugin "Build variant quick selector" but it only works when all modules have the same build variant selected.

Is there a way to change this manually in a project config file somewhere and then just restart android studio?

or

Is it possible to not rebuild each time I change a build variant and once done sync the project?